# Queries works Fine but the migration

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a small project using **Laravel 9 / Laravel Sail**. I have a weird error. my application queries works fine I can select, update, insert with no problem using Eloquent also. Everything is good.

Now I try to created a new migration and I try to push the migration using the usual `php arisan migrate` I'm getting an error message :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Temporary failure in name resolution (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = project and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

But by application works fine its connected to the database as I'm inserting and selecting, updating

the problem is just when I try to migrate which is weird.

my env :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=project
DB_USERNAME=username
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: `DB_HOST=mysql` the host is usually localhost or 127.0.0.1, depending on where your database is set up

Comment: ```DB_HOST``` is your database hosting environment no the DB itself that is most commonly ```localhost``` in case of mySQL or ```127.0.0.1``` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Laravel Sail, you should run:

```
sail artisan migrate
```

instead of:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Command 'sail' not found, but can be installed with:

Answer (score 1):

- you can try set DB_HOST=localhost
- or it can be DB_HOST=0.0.0.0
- next execute the

> php artisan config:clear

this command will help you, clear the cached config

- then you can run your migration

> php arisan migrate